# Unpacking a byte into 8 bytes, where the LSB of each byte corresponds to a bit of the original byte

Tags: c, bitwise, portability

I needed to unpack a byte into the LSBs of each byte in an 8-byte integer. After some testing, I derived a surprisingly efficient and elegant solution that uses magic numbers multiplication, though this is [nothing new](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14539116/16217248). Upon [further investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750902/16217248) I found a similar solution, and from that I have adopted another.

My first function `ex8` stores the least significant bit in the **least significant byte.** The second least significant bit into the second least significant byte, etc. They are extracted by bitshifting and masking.

The second function `ex8l` stores the least significant bit in the byte with the **least significant memory address.** So that will do the same as the other function on little-endian machines, but will have byteswapped results on a big-endian machine. I did that by producing the magic number using a union with individual bytes, so the value will depend on the byte order, and not the other way around.

```c
unsigned long long ex8(unsigned char n) {
    return n * 0x2040810204081ULL & 0x101010101010101ULL;
}
#include <assert.h>
unsigned long long ex8l(unsigned char n) {
    static_assert(sizeof(long long) >= 8);
    const union {
        unsigned char b[8];
        unsigned long long u;
    } static m = {128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1};
    return n * (m.u >> 7) & 0x101010101010101ULL;
}
```

Comment: Reading an inactive member of the union _could_ be an undefined behavior. I don't want to start yet another holy war, so no review from me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior) is an interesting reading.

Comment: @vnp As far as I can tell, doing so undefined behavior in C++, but defined behavior in C.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are various opinions, and I am not a qualified language lawyer. I do not approve such practices, but yet again, I do not approve holy wars even more.

Comment: @vnp I approve of practices that aren't undefined behavior, and assuming I'm using a conforming C compiler, not C++, I'm good do go with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reliance on a certain endian and width**

`ex8l()` code is not portable if a different endian is used.  *Description* has "but will have byteswapped results on a big-endian machine", yet such a critical restriction deserves to be in code and/or use a `static_assert()`.

If `unsigned long long` is wider than 64-bit, code fails too.  Use `uint64_t u;` in the union instead.  Signature `unsigned long long ex8l(unsigned char n)` remains a good choice.

**Unneeded use of `LL`**

`0x101010101010101ULL`  is sufficient as `0x101010101010101U`.  The `LL` serves no purpose here.

**What if `unsigned long long` is 128-bit?**

`0x2040810204081ULL` obliges a `unsigned long long` which may be much wider than 64-bit.

Consider `LL` may oblige 128-bit operations on future machines - although such machines will likely optimize.

Not a big issue with `0x2040810204081ULL`, but code could use `UINT64_C(0x2040810204081)` to not force excessive wide math.

**Wrong test**  (Covered by [@Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288960/29485))

`static_assert(sizeof(long long) >= 8);`, assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8` is not needed as C specifies the range of `long long` requiring at least 64-bits.

What would be useful is `static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8);` as OP's code relies on that.

Comment: The rationale for using `unsigned long long` and `unsigned char` in the union is so that it would work even for `CHAR_BIT > 8` as long as `sizeof(unsigned long long) >= 8` but I guess I had an oversight for the `0x101010101010101` mask which won't work as expected if `CHAR_BIT > 8`.

Comment: @user16217248 As `CHAR_BIT > 8` is so rare, I recommend to 1) not assume `CHAR_BIT == 8` when can can _easily_ be written portably and 2) when not #1, simply add a `_Static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8)` for byte dependent size code as this.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> static_assert(sizeof(long long) >= 8);
> ```

This might be over-cautious, since you're actually expanding into *octets* rather than necessarily `char` units.

We should be checking that `sizeof (long long) * CHAR_BIT >= 64` for this code.  Or, more likely, we want one bit in each *char* of output, so test `#if CHAR_BIT == 8` and provide an alternative implementation in the `#else` block.

---

I think that the unit tests should definitely have been presented with this code.  I would be more confident of its correctness if I could see which bit patterns were verified to work.  It's even amenable to an *oracle test* where all `UCHAR_MAX` values are compared against a clear, unoptimised reference implementation.